# How to change color of icons on each custom range steps

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a custom range I have styled and modified.

For each step there is a text value displayed underneath the range in a green box, and icons at the top of each step.

[image]

I would like to know, how can I change the background color of the icons when a step has been selected? I have added some additional javascript code that is not working properly.

For instance, on the first step, the group icon will be green, and when you select the next step the person will be green and the group will change to default grey, and so on and so forth...

Thank you.

```js
var arr = new Array();
arr[1] = "everyone";
arr[2] = "show my group only";
arr[3] = "show only me";

var rangeSlider = function() {
  var slider = $(".range-slider"),
    range = $(".range-slider__range"),
    value = $(".range-slider__value");

  slider.each(function() {
    value.each(function() {
      var value = $(this)
        .prev()
        .attr("value");
      $(this).html(arr[value]);
    });

    range.on("input", function() {
      $(this)
        .next(value)
        .html(arr[this.value]);
    });

    // Set active icons
    $('.range-icons li').removeClass('active selected');
    var icons = $('.range-icons').find('li:nth-child(' + icons + ')');
    icons.addClass('active selected');
    return style;
  });
};

rangeSlider();
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 60px 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    padding: 60px;
  }
}

.range-slider {
  margin: 0;
}

.range-slider {
  width: 24%;
}

.range-slider__range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /*width: calc(100% - (73px));*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d7dcdf;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2c3e50;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
}

.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__range:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2c3e50;
  cursor: grab;
  transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
}

.range-slider__range:active::-moz-range-thumb {
  cursor: grabbing;
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb:hover {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__value {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
  padding: 0;
}


/*.range-slider__value:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: -7px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid #2c3e50;
  border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}*/

::-moz-range-track {
  background: #d7dcdf;
  border: 0;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-outer {
  border: 0;
}


/*.range-labels {
  margin: 9px -21px 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.range-labels li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #b2b2b2;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.range-labels .active {
  color: #37adbf;
}
.range-labels .selected::before {
  background: #37adbf;
}
.range-labels .active.selected::before {
  display: none;
}*/


/*icons*/

.range-icons {
  margin: 9px -20px 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.range-icons li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #b2b2b2;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.range-icons .active {
  color: #37adbf;
}
.range-icons .selected::before {
  background: #37adbf;
}
.range-icons .active.selected::before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="range-slider">
  <ul class="range-icons clearfix">
    <li class="active selected"><i class="material-icons">group</i></li>
    <li><i class="material-icons">person</i></li>
    <li><i class="material-icons">lock</i></li>
  </ul>

  <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="1" min="1" max="3" step="1">
  <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I feel like you are having us build this thing for you one step at a time...

Comment: @Jordan S my javascript skills are not good. I am just asking for some help.

Comment: @Jordan S I have added some javascript code for it, but its not working properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create classes and add the apropriate class with `addClass` whenever the the range input changes in `range.on("input",` with

```
$('.material-icons:nth('+ ( this.value - 1) +')').addClass('class-'+(this.value))
```

since your `this.value` starts from `1` :

```js
var arr = new Array();
arr[1] = "everyone";
arr[2] = "show my group only";
arr[3] = "show only me";

var rangeSlider = function() {
  var slider = $(".range-slider"),
    range = $(".range-slider__range"),
    value = $(".range-slider__value");

  slider.each(function() {
    value.each(function() {
      var value = $(this)
        .prev()
        .attr("value");
       $(this).html(arr[value]);
    });

    range.on("input", function() {
      $(this)
        .next(value)
        .html(arr[this.value]);
        $('.material-icons').attr('class', 'material-icons')
      $('.material-icons:nth('+ ( this.value - 1) +')').addClass('material-icons class-'+(this.value))
    });
  });
};

rangeSlider();
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 60px 20px;
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    padding: 60px;
  }
}

.range-slider {
  margin: 0;
}

.range-slider {
  width: 24%;
}

.range-slider__range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /*width: calc(100% - (73px));*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d7dcdf;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2c3e50;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
}
.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  background: #1abc9c;
}
.range-slider__range:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: #1abc9c;
}
.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2c3e50;
  cursor: grab;
  transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
}
.range-slider__range:active::-moz-range-thumb {
  cursor: grabbing;
  background: #1abc9c;
}
.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb:hover {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__value {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
  padding: 0;
  
}
/*.range-slider__value:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: -7px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid #2c3e50;
  border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}*/

::-moz-range-track {
  background: #d7dcdf;
  border: 0;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-outer {
  border: 0;
}

/*.range-labels {
  margin: 9px -21px 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.range-labels li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #b2b2b2;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.range-labels .active {
  color: #37adbf;
}
.range-labels .selected::before {
  background: #37adbf;
}
.range-labels .active.selected::before {
  display: none;
}*/

/*icons*/
.range-icons {
  margin: 9px -20px 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.range-icons li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #b2b2b2;
  font-size: 10px;
}
/* classes with colors you want */
.class-1{
  color: red;
}
.class-2{
  color: blue;
}
.class-3{
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="range-slider">
<ul class="range-icons clearfix">
  <li class="active selected"><i class="material-icons class-1">group</i></li>
  <li><i class="material-icons">person</i></li>
  <li><i class="material-icons">lock</i></li>
</ul>

  <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="1" min="1" max="3" step="1">
  <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I meant change the icons color, not the text values background color.

Comment: this helped me out a lot. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

One methos I use is using svg icons and implement the raw code. You can then manipulate this source with clases and style settings.
Look inside the svg source and finmd the path and rect tags.

```js
document.getElementById("ranger").onchange = function(event) {

  document.querySelector(".symbol.standard").style.fill = "rgb(" + event.target.value + ", 80, 160)";
}
```

```css
svg {
width:200px;

.symbol.standard {
  fill: #f00;
}

.symbol.other {
  fill: rgb(80, 80, 160);
}
```

```html
<input id="ranger" type='range' min="0" max="255">
<svg class="singleseat " xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 90.3 63.3"> <title>seat</title> 
<rect class="symbol standard" x="16.7" width="57" height="49" rx="12" ry="12"></rect> 
<path class="symbol other" d="M79.9,15.8V42.3a12,12,0,0,1-12,12H22.5a12,12,0,0,1-12-12V15.8H0V51.3a12,12,0,0,0,12,12H78.3a12,12,0,0,0,12-12V15.8Z"></path> 
</svg>
```

Comment: this sounds interesting and different. I will keep this in mind. Thanks.